# Searching an agile method to create tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, gallio

I'm actually testing web service of a web. Working with unit testers like Nunit and Gallio.

Actually, i have a problem. I want to test a service where i have to fill a lot of data in the html, like a formulary. And the problem is that i'm doing that editing an xml manually to do the tests... its too labored and heavy, and because this, i'm searching an agile method to do that.

My boss told me to do a formulary where i can fill all the fields, like the html, and then, create a xml with that. Is more efficient than editing a base xml manually.

There is a tool that can help me?

Sorry about my bad english.

Comment: You mean - you are testing a web service by sending XML to it, and currently your having to hand-code the XML?

Answer (score 0):

You should try either [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [Fitness](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse).

Comment: i taked a look both of them but i think that is not what i want. Selenium is like Watin, it do tests but more presentation way. Im searching a tool to make tests more agile. The program tester its actually made.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe test data builders could work for you? You could write classes so that You can write in Your tests

```
var xml = new WebServiceCallBuilder()
             .WithDefaultValues()              // this sets most common options
             .WithParamX("something")          // which You can then modify
             .WithParamY("something other")
             .WithParamZ("another thing")
             .Build();

var result = webService.Call(xml);
```

You can also implement test data builder so that it enables things like

```
var xyzBuilder = new WebServiceCallBuilder()
                 .WithDefaultValues()
                 .WithParamX("x")
                 .WithParamY("y")
                 .WithParamZ("z");
var xyzXml = xyzBuilder.Build();

// let's say now You want similar builder but with different Z param
// then You can do this to not copy/paste/modify code above
var xyzzzBuilder = new WebServiceCallBuilder(xyzBuilder)
                      .WithParamZ("zzz");
var xyzzzXml = xyzzzBuilder.Build();
```

I would probably use it.

Answer (score 0):

We decided **not to unit test our code through the web service**, because of the effort involved in mocking the environment and the http requests.

Instead we move as much of our code as possible into a **'core' component**, which has no dependency on the web framework (in our case ASP.NET, so 'core' has no reference to assemblies like System.Web).

The code that is dependant on the web framework is left in the **'web' component**. We try to keep this as small as possible - it typically handles authentication, authorization,  translates the request and calls the appropriate functionality in 'core' to process it.

We try to unit test the public interface to 'core' completely, but we do not attempt to unit test the 'web' interface. We plan to test 'web' using a different kind of automated test.